# Firebase AB tests don't allow "App Version" targeting

Tags: firebase, firebase-remote-config

When we create a new Firebase AB test (Remote Config AB test for iOS app), the "Version" field is disabled in the targeting criteria (see image below).

The stream view of Firebase shows that Firebase correctly parsing the app version.

Any idea why this can't be selected? The feature we want to AB test isn't available in older builds, so we want to limit testing to the latest.

[image: Target dropdown]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can confirm this is a bug that was introduced recently.  Our engineers know about it, and are working on a fix that should be released soon.

Source: Firebase support